# When and How properly deactivate your audio session?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I'm a little bit lost with AVFoundation and you are my last hope !

I am writing a workout app in which I sometimes play short prompts, for instance : "You pedal for 10 minutes" or "Good !"

Apple recommends to activate the audio session just before play the prompt and to always deactivate it after the prompt is played. More than a recommendation this is really what I want because I use the option : AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers and I just want to duck the music player while the prompt is playing, not before, not after.

I don't know how to achieve that! Because I am not pretty sure of the way to deactivate the audio session, my first idea was to use a "while".

Here is my AudioController class:

```
#import "AudioController.h"

@interface AudioController ()


@property(strong,nonatomic)AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayerGood;

@end


@implementation AudioController

-(id)init
{
    self=[super init];
    if (self) {
        [self configureAudioSession];
        [self preparePlayers];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)configureAudioSession
{
    self.audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
    [self.audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers error:&setCategoryError];

}


-(void)preparePlayers
{
    NSError *initAudioPlayerError = nil;

    NSURL *urlGood = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Correct" ofType:@"caf"]];



    self.audioPlayerGood = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urlGood error:&initAudioPlayerError];

   if (initAudioPlayerError) {
        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",[initAudioPlayerError localizedDescription]);
    }


    [self.audioPlayerGood prepareToPlay];
 }

-(void)playCorrect
{
    NSError *activationError = nil;
    [self.audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError];
    [self.audioPlayerGood play];
    NSLog(@"****************Correct played***************");
    while (self.audioPlayerGood.playing) {
        break;
    }
    [self.audioSession setActive:NO error:&activationError];
 }


@end
```

Then I initialize an AudioController object in an other class in which I use the playCorrect method:

```
[self.audioController playCorrect];
```

But just after the sound is played the debug area print me this text :

> AVAudioSession.mm:646: -[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]: Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.

And if ten seconds later I want to play this sound again it will not work whereas the method playCorrect should reactivate the audio session... 
So I don't know what is the proper way to deactivate the audio session and when do it, if somebody could help me on this :)

Answer (score -2):

What is that while loop supposed to do?

You'd be better off listening for the player finishing playing, and then deactivating the session.

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
    selector:@selector(finishedPlaying:) 
    name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:playerItem];
```